# Blank {} created when passed the string to HTTP ENTITY class as a paramter

Tags: java, spring, restful-authentication

I have a String like this

```
String oauth_parameters ="&oauth_cosumer_key=231323 &oauth_signature=fsdfsdfsd"
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(oauth_parameters);
return entity;
```

But the return entity returns the string as

```
<&oauth_cosumer_key=231323 &oauth_signature=fsdfsdfsd,{}>
```

I cant find out why the blank braces is created at the end of the string.

Comment: Is that the `toString` output? I'd guess the `{}` is the `toString` of the `headers` field. What version of Spring is this?

Comment: Yeah,its giving a blank braces in the place of header field, I don't have a header in my api request I just need to send the body alone. Is there any method to send body alone

Comment: `HttpEntity.toString` was added in version 3.1 ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.1.x/org.springframework.web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.java)), and I can't find any version in which it would print the `headers` when the `HttpEntity(String)` constructor is used. Is that really the constructor you're calling?

Comment: `toString` methods are generally only used for debugging. I think what you want is `getBody()`?

Comment: I am new to restful I am totally confused

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with restful (I don't even know what that is). `HttpEntity` is a really simple class; just [look at the code and read exactly what it does](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.java).

Comment: the toString says it has the body that you provided as a string (why are you passing those parameters like that?) and that there are no headers, thus the empty braces